# IDEA was unable to find AspectJ compiler .jar among plugin dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, aop, aspectj

I'm using trying to use AspectJ with Intellij. I have enabled `Aspectj` plugins in intellij, `Spring AOP/@Aspectj`  and `Support Aspectj` and I have set the `ajc` compiler in `Setting ->  java compiler -> ajc`.

I get this error message.

```
AspectJ Support
IDEA was unable to find AspectJ compiler .jar among plugin dependencies.
Please fix <aspectj-maven-plugin> in '/home/manoj/stuff/moghul/Git_backend/dropwizard/pom.xml' and re-import a project,or set compiler manually via Settings | Compiler | Java Compiler.
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-graphite</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.astefanutti.metrics.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-aspectj</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <aspectLibraries>
            <aspectLibrary>
              <groupId>io.astefanutti.metrics.aspectj</groupId>
              <artifactId>metrics-aspectj</artifactId>
            </aspectLibrary>
          </aspectLibraries>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: as far as I remember IntelliJ will detect aspectJ when it finds the <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId> in the pom. Maybe try version 1.6.9? And then re-import the project. I would also argue that a dependency to <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId> is wrong. Maven plugins are no dependencies to be used that way - its fine in the plugins section.

Comment: I have the same issue, but with no resolution. Anyone found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it makes sense to also use a plugin version. I cannot see any in your POM. Or do you define one in a `pluginManagement` section? Just fix your POM and IntelliJ IDEA will work.

By the way:

- You use a very old AspectJ version. Why? Use the current one, as of today 1.8.8.
- The only dependency you need to declare for AspectJ compile-time weaving is `aspectjrt`. If you want AspectJ Maven plugin to upgrade its AspectJ version, define a plugin dependency on the desired version of `aspectjtools`, not a module dependency.

Feel free to ask follow-up questions if you do not fully understand this answer.

Comment: What was the downvote for? I gave the right answer. If something is wrong, please comment, don't just downvote. Besides, nobody else except me even cared to answer and the OP also didn't care to provide any feedback. Sometimes I really wonder why I am still doing this...

Comment: I have the same issue, but not sure of the solution yet. I keep getting the same error regardless of the changes I make.

Comment: @KayKay, your comment is too unspecific, I cannot help you like this. If my hints about how to fix this issue are not helping, either you are not using them at all, are using them incorrectly or your issue is a different one. Please post a new question with a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and comprehensive problem description. Then I can take a look.

Comment: I am using the latest version of aspectj as you have mentioned and not sure how to add the configuration in the plugin management section for aspectj. Also, this issue happens to me only in IntelliJ, seems to be a configuration issue in Intellij. It was working fine and when I cleared the .m2 repository and reimported all again, it started to give this error.